Pytest parameter id access in test
I am using pytest and I have the id set for each parameter of a test.
I use:
pytest.param([], id = "meaningful_string")

The test can access the param list. Is it also possible for the test to access the param id?

For what purpose? What are you actually trying to achieve?

the id typically has meaningful information. It could be used to create folders in the test that pertain to that id.

That sounds like a terrible idea, and a good way to get conflicts when running tests concurrently. If you need filesystem support you should use the tmp_path and tmpdir fixtures, whose job it is to handle that. The test id is a way for the runner to address tests, if you have semantics-relevant information it should be in the params (and by default param ids are derived from para values, so you get the ids for free).

Sometimes a  folder should bare the name of the test. It would be duplicating that info if you pass it in as parameter.

The id of a test can be acquired through the request fixture
request.node.callspec.id

Kudos to this post
